# Why is the time incorrect on my iPhone videos?

Tags: iphone, video, photos.app

When I import my photos and videos into iPhoto, the videos usually have the wrong timestamp, possibly two hours after the actual time. I.e., if I take a video alongside a photo, the photo displays correctly in time order at 3:30 but the video shows later because it has a 5:30 timestamp.

Why is this happening, and what can I do to stop it in the future? (Bonus: How can I easily rectify the time difference on the videos I've already imported?) Does this happen on all iPhone models or just the iPhone 5?

Comment: Is the time correct on the phone itself?

Comment: @Undo: Yes, and it is always correct on the photos but not the videos taken in the same period. I'll add that I've seen this happen between my previous iPhones and iPhoto installs over the years, as well.

Comment: I have the same problem. I found a work around which kinda works but not 100%. So, in Adobe Bridge I copy the "Date File Modified" (which for some reason is the correct time, and of course BEFORE you actually modify this file which would change the time to the current time rendering this method useless) to the Camera Data (EXIF) -> Date Time Original. Just select the date, copy and then paste into that other field. Suddenly the Date Created becomes correct. But..... when I upload this to my Google Photos album, the video is placed at the old 2 hour earlier location. So, not really fixed. Also,